# How to retrieve the total height for DataGrid's content in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a data grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Foo" ... />
```

I'd like to bind an element's height to the height of the data grid. Simply doing `{Binding ElementName=Foo, Path=ActualHeight}` will not work, because it takes the `ScrollViewer`'s height, not the total height of the data grid's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the DataGrid's internal `ScrollViewer`, and bind to it's `ViewportHeight`

Depending on what you're doing with this value and where you need it, this can be done in a variety of ways.

Typically this sort of thing is needed for a View-Only purpose, so I would put the code to find the ViewPort height in the CodeBehind

For example, using some [VisualTreeHelpers](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/), you could do something like this:

```
// Find first child of type ScrollViewer in object Foo
var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<ScrollViewer>(Foo);

// If object is found, set other control's height to ViewportHeight
if (scrollViewer != null)
{
    MyControl.Height = scrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
}
```

I can't remember if there's more than one `ScrollViewer` in a `DataGrid`... you'd have to use something like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out for sure. If there is, there's an overload of `.FindChild()` to find an element by name that you should be able to use. The name can be obtained through something like Snoop too.

This could also be done in a `Converter`, where you pass the `DataGrid` to a Converter, and have it find the `ScrollViewer` and `ViewportHeight` in the Converter

```
<Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=Foo, 
                       Converter={StaticResource GetDataGridContentHeight}}" />
```

**Edit**

I actually did a few tests, and the DataGrid's `ScrollViewer` treats sizes a bit differently, probably due to `Virtualization`. It appears to use relative sizes based on the number of rows.

The test `DataGrid` I was working with had 23 rows. The `ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight` was equal to 23, and `ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight` was 3, meaning there were 23 rows total, and  3 complete rows were being shown. The `ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight` was equal to 20, meaning I could scroll from 0 to 20 (since 3 items are shown, it doesn't need to go to 23), and the `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` was set to whatever item I was currently scrolled to.

So to get the actual content height of items in a virtualized `ScrollViewer`, I think you're going to have to get the `ActualHeight` of one of the visible rows, and multiply it by the `ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight` to get the actual size of your content. This will only work if the `Height` of all your items is the same though.

Comment: The visual tree helper is unable to find the scroll viewer? I used the helper code as is and tried it just like above. Is `Foo` the `DataGrid` instance?

Comment: @rFactor Yes, `Foo` is the name of the `DataGrid`. I did a quick test and it returns the `ScrollViewer` just find using that code. Are you by any chance using `VisualTreeHelper` instead of `VisualTreeHelpers`? (note the `s` at the end... I named it this before noticing something already existed that was named very similar)

Comment: The method says "Looks for a child control within a parent by type". So I think it's the right one. However, what do you mean by "Foo is the name of the DataGrid"? Name? You mean `Foo` is an instance of `DataGrid`?

Comment: @rFactor `Foo` would be your `DataGrid`. I wrote that line of code assuming you had `<DataGrid x:Name="Foo" ... />` in your XAML, however you could also make a variable called `foo` and set it equal to your DataGrid: `var foo = MyDataGrid;`

Comment: For some reason the visual tree helper returns always `null`. Both in code-behind `Initialize()` as well as when I use a converter (and yes I checked that the visual tree helper method gets the data grid instance for real), both by name and by type `ScrollViewer` do not work. Is it possible that the code runs too early and it doesn't exist?

Comment: I ran a task in another thread, slept for 5 seconds and invoked in current dispatcher, it now correctly found the scroll viewer :). Do you have suggestions as to how can I make the converter to work because now it gets invoked once and too early?

Comment: @rFactor I'm not sure, perhaps you could post your code in a new SO question and provide the link?

Comment: I will do it code-behind, listen to events on the data grid and recalculate the height. However, the `Loaded` event does not occur when I'm manually adding a new item, do you know if there's a better event for this (detecting when the total height has changed -- items removed/added)?

Comment: @rFactor There should be a `SizeChanged` event you can use, or perhaps use some kind of EventSystem like Prisms `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger` to broadcast a `CollectionChanged` event from the `ViewModel` whenever the collection changes, and the View can subscribe to listen for these messages and updated as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `DataGrid` in another `ScrollViewer` and then the DataGrid's actual height will be correct.

However this comes with a performance penalty of not being able to utilize the *row virtualization* of the `DataGrid`. You'd have to test and see if this has a significant negative  affect in your use case or not.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible in my scenario.

Comment: @rFactor because of the virtualization penalty I mentioned?