# Does WPF DataGrid fire an event when a row is added / removed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I wish to recalculate things everytime a DataGrid gets more rows or some are removed. I tried to use the `Loaded` event, but that was fired only once.

I found [`AddingNewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem%28VS.110%29.aspx), but that is fired before it has been added. I need to do my stuff *afterwards*.

There's also `LayoutUpdated`, which works, but I'm afraid it's not wise to use it, because it fires way too often for my purposes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your `DataGrid` is bound to something, I think of two ways of doing this.

You could try getting the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` collection, and subscribing to its `CollectionChanged` event. This will only work if you know what type of collection it is in the first place.

```
// Be warned that the `Loaded` event runs anytime the window loads into view,
// so you will probably want to include an Unloaded event that detaches the
// collection
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    if (dg == null || dg.ItemsSource == null) return;

    var sourceCollection = dg.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>;
    if (sourceCollection == null) return;

    sourceCollection .CollectionChanged += 
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_CollectionChanged);
}

void DataGrid_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Execute your logic here
}
```

The other solution would be to use an Event System such as Microsoft Prism's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger`. This means your `ViewModel` would broadcast a `DataCollectionChanged` event message anytime the bound collection changes, and your `View` would subscribe to receive these messages and execute your code anytime they occur.

Using `EventAggregator`

```
// Subscribe
eventAggregator.GetEvent<CollectionChangedMessage>().Subscribe(DoWork);

// Broadcast
eventAggregator.GetEvent<CollectionChangedMessage>().Publish();
```

Using `Messenger`

```
//Subscribe
Messenger.Default.Register<CollectionChangedMessage>(DoWork);

// Broadcast
Messenger.Default.Send<CollectionChangedMessage>()
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this in my code, adding the notify collection changed event handler, but my sourceCollection always is equal to "null".  I don't have the ViewModelBase as an available class for the ObservableCollection template . . . I am using VS 20113 (express) binding to a SQLServer 2014 express database, and WPF application.  I have not been able to find a missing "using" directive that would give me the ViewModelBase . . . what am I doing wrong?  Thanks Paul

Comment: @PaulGibson `ViewModelBase` is a custom class that I usually implement on all my ViewModels. In your case, just cast it to whatever type of item is in your ItemsSource.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that is what I figured after some googling.  So I have tried the class of the data table, as well as the row class (both the generic DataRow, and the specific class for my dataRow) and both yeild null for sourceCollection . . . I have posted a question that has the code blocks here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620496/wpf-datagrid-roweditending-event-to-call-update) . . . I'm sure that I'm doing something simple wrong, but can't find the right combo.

Comment: I have tried the second approach, EventAggregator in Prism. In this case when a new row is added to the DataGrid, the focus is already set to the next element. When I click on that row, the event fires as collection really changes at that point. Is there something that fires immediately when a new row is added to the datagrid, when CanUserAddRows is set to true?

Comment: @Vishal Personally I wouldn't use CanUserAddRows for this. I would either provide users with an "Add" button that adds a record to the source collection, or provide them with a blank item and whenever that blank item is populated, add a new blank item to take the place of the "New" row. Personally I prefer the first solution as I find extra blank rows in a grid often confuse users, and make it harder to validate as I always have to check if the item is a "new" item

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for the explaination. I will try it as you said, as I always like that users should feel free while using my application. If it is possible for you to share your final datagrid  layout then please share a screenshot of that.

Comment: For the first option, you can use INotifyCollectionChanged like `var sourceCollection = dg.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged`. This avoids having to know the concrete type used for generic and still lets you get the collection changed event.

Answer (score 2):

How about `DataGrid.LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)`?

Same for Unloading.

`DataGrid.UnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)`?

Comment: You can add new rows to the data source of a `DataGrid` without this event firing. This event is related to the visual rows (`DataGridRow` objects) and not the rows in the data source.

Comment: In that case bind your datagrid to `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Unloading fires just by moving away from the row not just for deletion

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried an MVVM approach and binding to an Observable collection?

```
public ObservableCollection<Thing> Items{
get { return _items; }
set{ _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Items");  // Do additional processing here 
}
}
```

So you can watch the add / remove of items without being tied to the UI?

Comment: Although this is the right way to handle collection changed events for application logic, I think the OP is asking about collection changed events for the View based on some comments in [another question of his](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11157916/302677)

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can go down the `RowUnloading` route as others have described here, however note that this event fires also every time a row is losing focus.

However by playing around I found that when a row is removed the `SelectedItem` property of the grid is null while the `CurrentItem` property is not null, and so far I have seen this combination only for a deleted row, (although I can't guarantee that I have not missed an exotic situation... however for the basic situations of moving away from the row I have not seen it so far).

So when can use the following code to filter for deleted rows only:

```
private void CategoriesGrid_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{     
        if (((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem != null || ((DataGrid)sender).CurrentItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // The rest of your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use ObservableCollection and get notification about add or another operation, the best way use INotifyCollectionChanged

```
var source = datagrid.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
```

Because, when you will unwrap to `ObservableCollection<MyClass>()`, you must write strogly MyClass (not `ObservableCollection<ParentOfMyClass>`())

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what "things" you want to recalculate, you might consider using the ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged attached event.  This can be set in XAML as follows:

```
<DataGrid
...
ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="control_ScrollChanged">
```

The [ScrollChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) object has various properties that can be helpful for computing layout and scroll position (Extent, Offset, Viewport).  Note that these are typically measured in numbers of rows/columns when using the default virtualization settings.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for solution to this and I have found the perfect event to handle this, the event is called **UnloadingRow**

```
<DataGrid ....
    UnloadingRow="DataGrid_UnloadingRow">
 ...
</DataGrid>
```

In your C# code u get this

```
private void ProductsDataGrid_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
   MyObject obj = (MyObject)e.Row.Item; // get the deleted item to handle it
   // Rest of your code ...
   // For example : deleting the object from DB using entityframework

}
```

Comment: This works when any row unloads visually, not logically; thus, it will fire anytime a row is unloaded and, if virtualizing, this may happen whether or not the item already existed prior to the operation. The ideal behavior is to fire only when an item is added or removed from the underlying collection.

Comment: Unloading fires just by moving away from the row not just for deletion