# Using stack panel - vertical + horizontal

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Can a `stack panel` grow vertically as well as horizontally ?

For eg,

If there are `3 stack panel items`, then,

`Item1`

`Item2`

`Item3`

If there are `5 stack panel items` then,

`Item1`  `Item4`

`Item2`  `Item5`

`Item3`

(At most in a row, there can be a maximum of `n` items. If it exceeds, a new row is started)

One more thing: I am creating the `stack panel items` at `run-time` (code-behind)!

```
this.itemsPanel.Children.Add(item1);
this.itemsPanel.Children.Add(item2);
this.itemsPanel.Children.Add(item3);
this.itemsPanel.Children.Add(item5);
```

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344938/list-items-vertically-on-a-wrappanel-and-take-advantage-of-multiple-columns

Comment: You either want a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Custom Panel](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a ListBox with a WrapPanel, but you prob want your objects to be the same size, width and height, which will be equal to your widest and tallest object, that's why we use a grid with IsSharedSizeScope with a WrapPanel.

```
<ListBox Name="ButtonList" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                 BorderThickness="0" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                 Padding="0"  
                 Background="Transparent" 
                 Margin="0"
                 Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                 >


            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- you need the grid, otherwise buttons are different heights depending on the control -->
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="row1"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col1"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!-- put some control here --> 

  </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```